# Angular Universal 14 Not work, Occurred Something weird error messages

Tags: typescript, server-side-rendering, angular9, angular-universal, angular14

1. **Issue**: Angular Universal (SSR) does not work
2. **Tech**: Angular version 14, Angular CLI, Angular Universal 14

I have created a **.net core 6 + angular 14** project

I don't know how to solve this for running angular universal.

I want to Apply Angular Universal In my latest Angular 14 Project, the **project previously worked in Angular 9** and after Upgrading to Angular 14 now I want to Apply angular Universal to my project.

same code run from two different places occurred different error

1. **Fist Error** :-This is the Screenshot of the **local machine terminal Error**

[image: This error from my local machine]

2. **Second Error**:- This is the Screenshot of the terminal Error, It's weird. **This Screenshot from the server terminal**
   [image: This is the Screenshot of terminal]

This is the package.json file code

```
{
  "name": "ezschoolangularapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/ng",
    "nx": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/nx",
    "start:serve": "npm run nx -- run zeta-frontend:serve",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44457 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44457 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run EzSchoolAngularApp:server",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run EzSchoolAngularApp:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist-server/main.js",
    "prerender": "ng run EzSchoolAngularApp:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.11.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14.2.3",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/braintree-web": "^3.62.2",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "^5.0.1",
    "angular-resize-event": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-sweetalert-service": "^2.0.2",
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "braintree-web": "^3.64.2",
    "card-validator": "^8.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.3.2",
    "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^5.3.2",
    "idle-session-timeout": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-fullcalendar": "^5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-plaid-link": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^16.2.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^14.0.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.3.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^14.2.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.10",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  }
}
```

This is server.ts file code

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { createWindow } from 'domino';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const scripts = readFileSync('dist/index.html').toString();
  const window: any = createWindow(scripts);

  (global as any).window = window;
  (global as any).document = window.document;
  (global as any).Event = window.Event;
  (global as any).KeyboardEvent = window.KeyboardEvent;
  
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I want to Apply Angular Universal In my latest Angular 14 Project, the project previously worked in Angular 9 and after Upgrading to Angular 14 now I want to Apply angular Universal to my project

Comment: Are you not hosting your angular app through the asp.net core app? ([Instructions](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976))